# Check if a Non-ASCII word exists in a string List

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, beautifulsoup

I have this list scraped from a web page

```
scraped = ['24 hour front desk', 'Bar / Lounge', 'Business centre', 'Café']
```

I want to check whether `Cafe` exists in the list or not?

I am doing this:

```
if "Caf" in scraped:
 print("Yes")
else:
 print("No")
```

It always prints *No* 
Reason I am writing `Caf` that from the scraped list, it always comes in non-ascii character `Café`

How can I perform this check without doing this `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if "Caf" in scraped:
```

checks if the literal string "Caf" is in the list, which it is not.

To check if "Caf" is in any of the strings in the list, use:

```
if any("Caf" in s for s in scraped)
```

To check for non-ascii characters, you can always use unicode escape sequences:

```
>>> "Caf\xe9" == 'Café' 
True`
```

Comment: how can i make my code work with `if "Café" in scraped:`

Comment: `if any("Caf\xe9" in s for s in scraped):` or `if "Caf\xe9" in scraped`:, depends on wether you want a match if "Café" appears anywhere in a list item or you require a whole match.

Answer (score 1):

ch3ka's answer solves the problem in your code. Here is an alternative for this type of problem.

You can use the [awesome-slugify](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/awesome-slugify) module to deal with these characters, for example

```
from slugify import slugify

print(slugify('Café')) # outputs 'Cafe'
```